# Fast way to update table and drop column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-workbench

I have a fairly simple procedure to run in mySQL. I have a table with a column called "temp" which is a varchar, I want to format this and place it in the column called "timestamp" which is (obviously) a timestamp.

"temp" is not in the correct format in the .csv file hence I have to do some calculations in order to make it in timestamp format. Here is how I have done it:

```
update tbl set timestamp=(concat(left(temp,4), '-', substr(temp,5,2), '-', substr(temp,7,2), right(temp,13)));
```

If there is a way to load it directly into the table as I use "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" that would work too - any faster implementation will be great!

Another update is the following which is extremely slow:

```
update tbl set thour=hour(timestamp);
```

The third performance blocker is this statement that only deletes a column - wondering why that should take so long time..

```
alter table tbl drop column temp;
```

Any suggestions what I could do with these statements to optimize performance as this is stupidly what prevents me from running a large query.

Comment: Are you reading from a .CSV and populating a table? That way you can read tha non formated time stamp value and calculate its correct value just before bumping to the DB, Also using that temp column is not a smart move, I'm sure you can refact the whole thing to improve it but is likely it you need some time and effort from you

Comment: Hey can you give us a sample line from your CSV to work with?  Would help us give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: @Marco Singh as for second and third "performance blockers" an index might come in handy. Refering to first point, you could isolate necessary data elsewhere and perform an update there so that you could use index on timestamp column by updating with already properly formatted column. That's my thought